# Error en condicional php

Tags: php, condiciones, lógica, formato-condicional

Tengo estas variables.

Necesito calcular si la suma de `equipo1 + equipo 2` es mayor a `2` el valor es alto de lo contrario el valor es bajo.

Igualmente para el resultado si es mayor a `2` es alto y menor a `2` es bajo.

Y compararlos entre si

Si la suma del resultado es alto y la suma de los equipos es alto entonces son `3 puntos` de lo contrario son `0 puntos`

```
$equipo1 = 1;
$equipo2 = 0;
$resultado1= 1;
$resultado2 = 2;
$sumaequipo = $equipo1 + $equipo2;
$sumaresultado = $resultado1 + 
$resultado2;
```

Lo hago así pero siempre me da ganador

```
$equipo1 = 1;

$equipo2 = 0;

$resultado1= 1;


$resultado2 = 2;

$altaresultado = "alta";

$altaapuesta = "alta";

$bajaresultado ="baja";

$bajaapuesta ="baja";

$gana= 3;

$pierde = 0;

$sumaequipo = $equipo1 + $equipo2;

$sumaresultado = $resultado1 + $resultado2;

if ($sumaresultado >2) {
    echo $altaresultado;
}else {
    echo $bajaresultado;
}

if ($sumaequipo >2) {
    echo $altaapuesta;
}else {
    echo $bajaapuesta;
}


if ($altaapuesta == $altaresultado) {
    echo $gana;
}else {
    echo $pierde;
}

if ($bajaapuesta == $bajaresultado) {
    echo $gana;
}else {
    echo $pierde;
}
```

Comment: Cambias los valores de las variables equipo1 y equipo2 cuando haces pruebas? Utilizas algún formulario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
<?php
// Tengo estas variables.
$equipo1 = 1;
$equipo2 = 0;
$resultado1= 1;
$resultado2 = 2;

$gana= 3;
$pierde = 0;
$sumaequipo = $equipo1 + $equipo2;
$sumaresultado = $resultado1 + $resultado2;

// Necesito calcular si la suma de equipo1 + equipo 2 es mayor a 2 el valor es alto de lo contrario el valor es bajo.
if ($sumaequipo >2) {
    $resultado_calculo_sumaequipo = "alta";
    echo "alta";
} else {
    $resultado_calculo_sumaequipo = "baja";
    echo "baja";
}

// Igualmente para el resultado si es mayor a 2 es alto y menor a 2 es bajo.
if ($sumaresultado >2) {
    $resultado_calculo_sumaresultado = "alta";
    echo "alta";
} else {
    $resultado_calculo_sumaresultado = "baja";
    echo "baja";
}

// Y compararlos entre si
if ($resultado_calculo_sumaequipo == $resultado_calculo_sumaresultado) {
    echo $gana; 
} else {
    echo $pierde;
}

// Si la suma del resultado es alto y la suma de los equipos es alto entonces son 3 puntos de lo contrario son 0 puntos

if (($resultado_calculo_sumaresultado == "alta") and $resultado_calculo_sumaequipo == "alta") {
    echo $gana;
} else {
    echo $pierde;
}
```

y si no lo comprendes te lo explico extendidamente.